# is_page_template showing partial results

Tags: php, templates, custom-header

Trying to load conditional content thru the header, but only front page is being identified correctly.  Archive, post and custom type templates aren't.

[image]

Using Query Monitor to identify correct template and used that template name as argument, with and without child theme folder declaration, but every other template falls into the else conditional.

```
    <?php
/* Conditional AD script loading */

/* Front page */
if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
    echo "Front page";
} elseif ( is_page_template(  'single-listing.php' ) ) {
    echo "Listing page template";
} elseif ( is_archive() ) {
    echo "Archive page template";
} elseif ( is_page_template( $template  ='single.php' ) ) {
    echo "Post template";
} else {
    echo "wrong template";
}

?>
```

PHP `elseif` is in header of child theme, template files are within child theme folder too. What am I missing?

Comment: read https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post and https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Post_Page and https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Page.2C_a_Single_Post.2C_an_Attachment_or_Any_Other_Custom_Post_Type

Comment: `is_page_template()` only checks if the page is using a custom page template, not if which template is being loaded. If you want to check for a singular listing you need to use `is_singular( 'listing' );`

Answer (score 1):

The `is_page_template()` function is for checking if the current page is using a specific [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use). That being a template selected from the *Template* dropdown in the *Page Attributes* box when editing the page.

The WordPress conditional tags are not based around which template files are used. They are used to tell you what content is being viewed, regardless of which template files are present in a theme. For example, `is_category()` will return `true` when viewing a category archive, even if your theme does not have a `category.php` file.

The list of available conditional tags is documented [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/references/list-of-conditional-tags/).

If you want to use Query Monitor to figure out what conditionals to use for what pages, use the *Conditionals* tab:

[image: Screenshot of query monitor with the conditionals tab active]